# difference between reserved bits and undefined bist in intel 8086 processor's flag register

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-16

In the 16-bit flags register of the intel 8086 processor there are 9 flags (each 1-bit, bit numbers 0,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11 which we know them as ZF,OF,...) the bit numbers 1,3,5 are marked as"U" (undefined) and the bit numbers 12,13,14,15 are marked as "R" (reserved).

My question is that what is the difference between **reserved** bits and the **undefined** bits in the intel 8086 processor?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved bits may be defined. Undefined bits never are. If a bit is "reserved", it is reserved for some specific purpose. If it's "undefined", then at that point no purpose for it was decided.

For example, if a bit sets a particular testing mode that users are never supposed to enable, the bit would be reserved but it wouldn't be undefined.

Comment: thanks for the answer. in this specific topic what is the purpose of keeping the bits 12,13,14 and 15 reserved? for example are they useful in the assembly shift commands such as SAR and SHR or they're kept reserved for testing purposes ?

Comment: I don't think it's publicly known. What we do know is that 12 and 13 became the I/O privilege level and 14 became the nested task flag on larger processors. But so far as I know, nobody has publicly stated what Intel had in mind when they initially reserved those flags.

Answer (score 3):

Reserved almost always means "Reserved for future use", to allow Intel to add extensions in later CPUs.

None of the flags are "undefined" - they are all either defined or reserved. What you've probably seen is a table describing how each instruction effects different flags, where the effect of a specific instruction on a specific flag may be undefined (even though that specific flag is not an undefined flag). An example of this is the IDIV instruction which leaves most of the defined flags (overflow, carry, etc) in an undefined state.

Comment: +1 The undefined for IDIV etc. means that current micro-architecture that uses 30-100 clock cycles to iterate over div instruction, can modify some flags -- it's deterministic of course, but it's best described as undefined.